# Receber um array no controller a partir do javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, array

Estou a criar um array com uma lista de dados em javascript:

`var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.keys;`

Onde tenho o resultado:

```
[278, 279, 280, 281, 282]
```

Que são `id's` de elementos de uma tabela Devexpress. Agora estou a tentar passar este array para o o meu controller, só está sempre a receber `null`.

**A minha função js**

```js
function downloadListaGARSTratadas() {
    var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.keys;
    alert(myArray);
    window.location.href = "/GAR/downloadListaGARsTratadas?GarsFiltro=" + myArray +"";
}
```

**Função no controller**

```cs
public ActionResult downloadListaGARsTratadas(int[] GarsFiltro)
{ ... }
```

Caso faça `string` em vez de `int[]` recebo `278, 279, 280, 281, 282`, ou seja a variável. Não é possível receber mesmo com um array de inteiros?

Comment: Você dever especificar que se trata de um array assim: `window.location.href = "/GAR/downloadListaGARsTratadas?GarsFiltro[]=" + myArray +""`, de uma olhada [nesse link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) do SO-EN e [nesse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter) que tratam esse assunto.

Comment: Sim, e até faz sentido usar `GarsFiltro[]=" + myArray +""`, mas continuo a receber `null` na mesma

Comment: Ok. é que esqueci de uma detalhe vou postar como resposta se não resolver eu removo.

Comment: Você não esta utilizando o JQuery? Você teria mais facilidade e controle fazendo uma chamada ajax.

Comment: Sim @lionbtt, estou a utilizar jquery. Acabei por fazer com javascript, mas também posso tentar com ajax. Apesar de não achar que o problema seja daí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você dever especificar que se trata de um array assim e passar cada valor como um parâmetro, só que todos com o mesmo nome, por exemplo:

```
/?arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz&arr[]=foo
```

Ou ainda assim para algums casos (como o ASP MVC):

```
/?arr=foo+bar&arr=baz&arr=foo
```

Como demostrado [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) e [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter) tópico do SO-EN e [nesse post](http://www.paulund.co.uk/parse-url-querystring-into-array-in-php)

Então em seu caso você deve fazer algo do tipo:

```js
window.location.href = "/GAR/downloadListaGARsTratadas?GarsFiltro=1&GarsFiltro=2&GarsFiltro=3"
```

Para gerar esse parâmetro de forma dinâmica criei esse método:

```js
function formatQueryStringURLParamArray(key, array){
    var param = "";
    for(var item in array){
        if(param.length > 0)
            param += "&";
        param += key + "=" + item;
    }
    return param;
}
```

Que pode ser chamado dessa forma, retornando a querystring formatada:

```js
var param = formatQueryStringURLParamArray("key", myArray);
```

Aqui tem um [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/V2qXd/).

**Exemplo com Web API**

Tente o seguinte teste (eu utilizo WebApi ASP MVC, mas é bem similar a MVC):

Criei o seguinte ApiController:

```cs
public class Test2Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual int Get([FromUri]int[] i)
    {
        return i.Length;
    }
}
```

E fiz a seguinte requisição via url em meu browser:

```
http://localhost:59402/api/test2/?i[]=1&i[]=2&i[]=3
```

E recebi corretamente o array de inteiros.

> Não sei se MVC usa isso, pois não trabalho com MVC apenas WebAPi, mas tente adicionar `[FromUri]` antes de seu parâmetro de array no método do Controller.

**Exemplo com ASP MVC**

Criei esse Controller:

```cs
public class Test3Controller : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index([FromUri]int[] i)
    {
        return Json(i, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

E fiz a seguinte requisição via url em meu browser:

```
http://localhost:59402/test3/?i=1&i=2&i=3
```

> *Note:* não sei por que razão o MVC não entendia quando eu passava `i[]`, então se eu passo apenas `i={valor}`, ele entende. Já Web API funcionava das duas formas: `i={valor}` e `i[]={valor}`.

Comment: O que estas a dizer, é que para cada elemento do array tenho de fazer um `GarsFiltro[]=` ?

Comment: @CesarMiguel, Sim, não encontrei documentação que diga isso, mas é assim que se faz para passar array por querystring. Só não sei se com asp mvc isso funciona. Tentou?

Comment: Sim tentei agora, não recebo na mesma o `[1,2,3]` que devia receber usando o teu exemplo

Comment: @CesarMiguel, está a receber nulo? Ou outra coisa?

Comment: Estou a receber nulo

Comment: @CesarMiguel, de uma olhada no exemplo que fiz com WebApi, na edição da resposta, e verifique seu controller.

Comment: @CesarMiguel, de uma olhada na edição adicionei um exemplo com ASP MVC.

Comment: já vi a tua solução e continuava a não conseguir... Vou postar aqui uma resposta com uma "solução" deste problema

Answer (score 0):

@CesarMiguel, o erro que você esta tendo não tem nada a ver, porém segue uma segunda opção de realizar esse processo via ajax e utilizando Json.

```
var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.keys;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArray);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GAR/downloadListaGARsTratadas",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
});
```

Comment: Por ajax continua a dar o mesmo erro. Tive de adicionar `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` antes de fazer o pedido (funcionou)

Answer (score 0):

Estava com um problema semelhante e encontrei o seguinte link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288462/c-sharp-mvc-4-passing-javascript-array-in-view-to-controller

Veja se isso te ajuda:

Existe um parâmetro, chamado `traditional`, que você configura no Ajax como `true` que envia o array javascript certo para o seu controller. `traditional : true,`

Tenho um array, chamado turno, no meu javascript que irei passar para o meu Controller via Ajax.

Turno é um array com os dias da semana... turno = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 4 mais...]

No javascript tenho a chamada via Ajax...

```
$.ajax({
        url: getBaseUrl() +  "GraphicsReport/FiltraDadosGrafico1",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional : true,
        data: {cDataInicial: dataInicial, cDataFinal: dataFinal, cLinha: linha, cTurno: turno, cModelo: modelo},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //Faz alguma coisa...
        },
        error: function (data) {
           //Faz alguma coisa...
        }
    });
```

No meu controller recebo...

```
public JsonResult FiltraDadosGrafico1(string cDataInicial, string cDataFinal, string cLinha, Array cTurno, string cModelo)
{
  string retCode = "Success";

  //Faz alguma coisa e retorna um Json

  return Json(new { retorno = retCode } );
}
```

Veja se isso pode te ajudar. Para mim, resolveu...

Answer (score -1):

Como não consegui resolver este problema retornando uma lista de inteiros para o controller, vou deixar aqui uma resposta com a minha solução (se bem que não era assim que gostava de resolver):

Na função javascript retorno o array para o controller como já tinha feito:

```
function downloadListaGARSTratadas() {
    var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.keys;
    window.location.href = "/GAR/downloadListaGARsTratadas?GarsFiltro=" +myArray +"";
}
```

No controller em vez de receber um array de inteiros, mandei receber uma string, devolvendo os valores como `201,202,203,204`:

```
public FileResult downloadListaGARsTratadas(string GarsFiltro)
{
   var arr = GarsFiltro.Split(',');
}
```

Fiz um `split` para a variável `arr` e ele cria o array

Comment: Cesar, o nome disso é "Gambiarra", hehe, isso não é uma boa abordagem, eu testei aqui com WebApi e MVC no Asp.net (MVC 4) e funcionou [minha solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27225/2998) perfeitamente, recomendo refazer [meu exemplo simples](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27225/2998) em seu ambiente e verificar por que não está funcionando (Te garanto que funciona). Se tiver alguma duvida posso te ajudar.

Comment: @Fernando, fui testar agora o teu exemplo e realmente funciona!